# change the icon of bootstrap panel

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I make a one faq script in PHP I want to change the icon when I open the panel and close the panel.I have tried these code but not get success.So what is the error in my code?

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-12 ">  
                        <?php  $v1 = ''; foreach($var as $data){ ?>

                            <div class="faqHeader" id="<?php echo  str_replace(' ','',$data['name']);?>"> <?php echo $data['name'];?> </div>                

                            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                                <?php   foreach($data['data'] as $dat){ ?> 
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#col<?php
                                                echo $v1;?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="col<?php
                                                echo $v1;?>">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right"></span>
                                                    <?php echo $dat['questions'];?>
                                                </a>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="col<?php echo $v1;?>" class="panel-collapse collapse"  role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <?php echo $dat['answer'];?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                               <?php $v1=$v1+1; } ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>  
                </div>


<script>
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});

</script>
```

Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

**`css solution`**

```
.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed:after{
    content: "+";
    float: right;
}
.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"]:after {
    content: "-";
    float: right;
}
```

```css
.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed:after{
    content: "+";
    float: right;
}
.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"]:after {
    content: "-";
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#aaa">
      aaa
     </a>
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="aaa" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
     aaa<br>
     aaa
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- .panel -->

  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#bbb">
      bbb
     </a>
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="bbb" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
     bbb<br>
     bbb
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

---

**`Js solution`**

```
$("#accordion, #bs-collapse").on("show.bs.collapse",function(a){ 
    $(a.target).prev('.panel-heading').addClass('active'); 
});
$("#accordion, #bs-collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse',function(a){ 
    $(a.target).prev('.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
});
```

```js
   $("#accordion, #bs-collapse").on("show.bs.collapse",function(a){ 
  $(a.target).prev('.panel-heading').addClass('active'); 
 });
   $("#accordion, #bs-collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse',function(a){ 
    $(a.target).prev('.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
 });
```

```css
.panel-heading a:after {
    content: "+";
    float: right;
}
.panel-heading.active a:after {
    content: "-";
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading active">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#aaa">
      aaa
     </a>
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="aaa" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
     aaa<br>
     aaa
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- .panel -->

  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#bbb">
      bbb
     </a>
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="bbb" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
     bbb<br>
     bbb
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```